# In a while loop in C, where i have a char[..] declared, do i have to clear it each iteration?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

In a while loop in C, where i have a char[..] declared, do i have to clear it each iteration?
Eg:

```
while (clock() < endTime) { 
    char buf[1000];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf); // Is this necessary?
}
```

Will the buffer be initialised each iteration of the loop to all zeroes automatically? Is my memset redundant?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local objects in C languauge are never initialized automatically. You have to supply an initializer. Otherwise, the object will contain garbage.

So, your `memset` is not really "redundant". However, the proper way to initialize a buffer to all-zeros is

```
char buf[1000] = { 0 };
```

and not `memset`. (Although in this case `memset` will work as well, it is almost always preferable to use a core language feature than a library function).

And yes, if you declare your buffer inside the cycle body, you have to reinitialize it every time.

Of course, the real question is: do you really need a buffer initialized to all-zeros every time you iterate? If so, then you have to do it every time.

Comment: If i move the declaration (char buf[1000]) outside the loop, and in the loop have 'buf={0}', will that work? It's not going to change the pointer, right?

Comment: @Chris: If you move the declaration outside, then you won't be able to use the `= { 0 }` syntax inside the cycle. This syntax can only be used in array initialization, but not in later assignment (arrays are non-assignable). In this case you'll have to resort to `memset`.

Answer (score 1):

The memset is not redundant. At each new loop your `buf` variable will be re-allocated on the stack. The space is NOT checked or zero'd automatically, you get what you get. Odds are pretty good that the first few bytes will be garbage thanks to your call off to `clock` (each time you call that it will use space on the stack). So yes, calling memset is necessary. However as an optimization, you may want to declare buf outside of the loop to avoid implicitly de-allocating and re-allocating each time.

Of course, the real question is: do YOU need it to be all zeros each time, or is this just a sick sick form of OCD (don't worry, I do it too).

Comment: Yep all zeroes each time is necessary otherwise i won't be able to treat it as an asciiz string.

Comment: @Chris: ASCIIZ strings only need one terminating NUL character, and the C library functions (e.g. `strcpy`, `strcat`, `sprintf`) are all designed to keep one there while you operate on the string: it's NOT generally a good idea (from an efficiency perspective) to initialise the entire buffer to NULs.